# ionic EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

code run

```
ionic Cordova build android --prod --release
```

Error

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile 'T:\ionic\T\platforms\android\platform_www\cordova-js-src\android\nativeapiprovider.js' 
-> 'T:\ionic\T\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www\cordova-js-src\android\nativeapiprovider.js'
```

What can i do please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran cmd separately in administrator mode and it fixed the problem for me. I don't know if it's the real solution to the problem. (Windows)